# Use NVL logic only on selected columns spark dataframe scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I need to replace only null values in selected columns in a dataframe. I know we have `df.na.fill` option . How can we implement it only on selected columns or is there any better option other than using `df.na.fill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) we can see that fill is well suited for your need. You can do something like:

```
df.na.fill(0, Seq("colA", "colB"))
```